# EDAMUserException(errorCode=2, parameter='Note.guid')

Tags: python-3.x, evernote

I just set up Evernote Sandbox and trying to practice search and download detail notes. The following is my code:

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
from evernote.edam.notestore.ttypes import RelatedQuery, NoteFilter, NotesMetadataResultSpec
dev_token = "DEV CODE FOR SANDBOX"
client = EvernoteClient(token=dev_token, sandbox=True)
userStore = client.get_user_store()
user = userStore.getUser()
```

print username is Ok
    print(user.username)
create new note is Ok
    note = ttypes.Note()
    note.title = "I'm a test note!"
    note.content = ''
    note.content += 'Hello, world!'
    note = noteStore.createNote(note)
search-notes is Ok:

```
from evernote.edam.notestore import NoteStore

filter = NoteStore.NoteFilter()
filter.words = "test"

filter.ascending = False

spec = NoteStore.NotesMetadataResultSpec()
spec.includeTitle = True

ourNoteList = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(dev_token, filter, 0, 100, spec)

for note in ourNoteList.notes:
    print("{} :: {}".format(note.guid, note.title))
```

But download the detail note is not Ok:

```
wholeNotes = []
for note in ourNoteList.notes:
    print(note.guid)
    wholeNote = noteStore.getNote(dev_token, note.guid, True, False, False) 
    print("Content length: %d" % wholeNote.contentLength)
    wholeNotes.append(wholeNote)
```

I got following Error:
[Error Msg pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGrm1.jpg)
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

[NoteStore.getNote](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) needs 1 guid and 4 booleans. `noteStore.getNote(dev_token, note.guid, True, False, False, False)` or `noteStore.getNote(note.guid, True, False, False, False)` should work in your case.